# C Gtk+2 Glade3: how can i set a SourceBuffer to a GtkSourceView that was loaded from glade?

Tags: c, gtk, glade, gtksourceview

I'm trying to load a .c file into a `GtkSourceView` widget.

Using C Language, with Gtk+ 2.22.1 and Glade 3.6.7 and GtkSourceView 2.10.1.

I noticed that in Glade UI I can only configure a `SourceView` to hold a `TextBuffer`; I did not find a `SourceBuffer` component.  So, I created a `SourceView` in Glade without a default buffer.  Now I want to set the `SourceBuffer` to be the buffer of my `SourceView` component.

`gtk_source_view_new_with_buffer()` is the only way I found to attach a `SourceBuffer` to a `SourceView`.  The problem is that this function is creating a `SourceView` and I want to attach a `SourceBuffer` to an already created `SourceView` built with Glade.  How can I do that?

I didn't paste any code because there is no code to show.  I just created a Glade file with some UI component plus the `SourceView-2` component with ID `gtk_sourceview`.

In the C file I fetch the SourceView component with

```
GtkSourceView *sourceview = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "gtk_sourceview"));
```

What's missing is how to create a `SourceBuffer` and attach it to the `SourceView` component.

Thanks!

**Update:**  I tried using:

```
GtkSourceBuffer *sourcebuffer = GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER(gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(sourceview)));
```

But I got the following assert error:

```
(tour_de_gtk:13884): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_text_view_get_buffer: assertion `GTK_IS_TEXT_VIEW (text_view)' failed
```

What can I do to resolve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: do you get any compile warnings, from my point of view you should get at least one about incompatible pointer when decalring and setting sorucebuffer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GtkSourceView` already has a buffer. Get it the same way you get a regular text buffer:

```
GtkSourceBuffer *buffer = GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER(gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(source_view)));
```

This is because `GtkSourceView` is a subclass of `GtkTextView`, so text view functions work on it too.

**EDIT**:

Here is a program and glade file that works.

Program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtksourceview/gtksourceview.h>
#include <gtksourceview/gtksourcebuffer.h>
#include <gtksourceview/gtksourcelanguagemanager.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if(gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "sourceview.ui", NULL) == 0)
        g_error("In real code, you would handle an error here");
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    GtkWidget *window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
    GtkSourceView *sourceview = GTK_SOURCE_VIEW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "gtk_sourceview"));

    /* Get the buffer */
    GtkSourceBuffer *sourcebuffer = GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER(gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(sourceview)));

    /* Do stuff to the buffer, to prove we've really got the GtkSourceBuffer */
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(sourcebuffer),
        "def hello():\n\tprint 'This should be highlighted as Python'\n", -1);
    GtkSourceLanguageManager *manager = gtk_source_language_manager_get_default();
    GtkSourceLanguage *python = gtk_source_language_manager_get_language(manager, "python");
    gtk_source_buffer_set_language(sourcebuffer, python);

    /* Okay, that should prove it, now run the program */
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtksourceview 3.0 -->
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.20"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkSourceBuffer" id="gtksourcebuffer">
    <property name="max_undo_levels">0</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="default_width">300</property>
    <property name="default_height">300</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="gtk_main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="hscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
        <property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSourceView" id="gtk_sourceview">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="left_margin">2</property>
            <property name="right_margin">2</property>
            <property name="buffer">gtksourcebuffer</property>
            <property name="tab_width">4</property>
            <property name="auto_indent">True</property>
            <property name="indent_on_tab">False</property>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: I see; it's a bug. In GtkBuilder, the `GtkSourceView` is created with a `GtkTextBuffer` buffer, as opposed to what would happen if you created the widget by hand. I have written a program that works; you have to create the `GtkSourceBuffer` in Glade and add it to the source view widget. See my edit.